# VS do not write to the output file

Tags: c#, file, output

Visual Studio do not write to the output file.
Code works and the result displays on the console but not on the file. 
Tried to change file destination and dir but without a result.

this is my code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\a.petkov\\Downloads\\FILES\\",
    "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

foreach (string file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
Console.WriteLine();

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>>();

foreach (string file in files)
{
    //decimal length = (new System.IO.FileInfo(file).Length) / 1024;
    decimal filesize = Decimal.Divide(file.Length, 1024);

    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
    string name = Path.GetFileName(file);

    if (dict.ContainsKey(extension))
    {
        dict[extension].Add(name, filesize);
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add(extension, new Dictionary<string, decimal>() { { name, filesize } });
    }
}
string wayToFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\report.txt";


    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(wayToFile))
    {
        foreach (var item in dict.OrderByDescending(v => v.Value.Count).ThenBy(k => k.Key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine('.' + item.Key);
            foreach (var kvp in item.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"--{kvp.Key} - {kvp.Value}kb");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post links to your code - instead, add a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lines 36 & 39

```
Console.WriteLine('.' + item.Key);
Console.WriteLine($"--{kvp.Key} - {kvp.Value}kb");
```

should be

```
writer.WriteLine('.' + item.Key);
writer.WriteLine($"--{kvp.Key} - {kvp.Value}kb");
```